# Creating new RegExp object removing one character from variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to isolate a word in each string, and that word is variable based on query params. The user searches for a term, and then I filter the API results to look for songs just containing that word (e.g. if I search for "help" then "help is on the way" is fine, but "helpless" isn't).

When I hardcoded a search term previously it worked just fine:

```
const songRegex = /\bhelp\b/g;
```

I console logged the search term + the song title returned from the API, then below that logged the result of testing the song title agains the regex:

[image]

To use variables, I discovered I should create a `new RegExp` object. The current (failing) regex is as follows:

```
const songRegex = new RegExp("\b" + searchTerm + "\b", "g");
```

Here's I'm also logging the regex itself and, no matter what I put in, the last character of the search term will be removed. "help" -> "hel"; "helping" -> "helpin".

[image]

Full code here:

```
const filteredSongsArray = [];
songsJSON.tracks.items.map((obj) => {
  const songTitle = obj.name.toLowerCase();
  const searchTerm = context.params.word.toLowerCase();

  const songRegex = new RegExp("\b" + searchTerm + "\b", "g"); // creating the regex
  const regexTest = songRegex.test(songTitle);
  
  console.log(searchTerm + " + " + songTitle);
  console.log(regexTest);

  if (obj.explicit === true || regexTest === false) {
    return;
  } else {
    filteredSongsArray.push(obj);
    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: `const songRegex = new RegExp("\\b" + searchTerm + "\\b", "g");`

Comment: I am 99.9% sure I tried that and it didn't work... But it did this time, so thank you for the tip!